# If you include const in a function, is & redundant?

Tags: c++

Will the two function specifications below always compile to the same thing? I can't see that a copy would be needed if you're using const. If they aren't the same, why?

```
void(const int y);
void(const int& y);
```

Comment: `const` just means the function can't modify the value of `y`, but that has no effect on whether `y` itself is passed by value (copy) or by reference.  Two different things. Consider what happens when `int` is changed to a non-POD class type. Then the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference becomes more apparent.

Comment: Ah, so if you have const but don't include &, it still copies?

Comment: Yes, it still makes a local copy, since it is pass-by-value.

Comment: technically there is also difference between `const int y` and `int y` as well, especially in case of non-trivial types. E.g. you can't pass the former as non-const easily or can't call  methods that aren't const. Even if that's a local copy.

Comment: @Swift, not technically, but very practically. Even with built-in types.

Comment: Why is this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same. If the argument changes after it's passed (e.g. because it's changed by another thread), the first version is unaffected because it has a copy. In the second variant, the function called may not change the argument itself, but it would be affected by changes to `y`. With threads, this might mean it requires a mutex lock.

Answer (score 0):

Without optimization ... this is not the same.

The first line of code gets a copy of the value passed into this function.

The second line of code gets the reference of the variable and your function will read the value always directly from the calling location variable .

In both cases the compiler is informed (by the keyword const), that these variables (inside the function) MUST not be modified. If there are any modifications in the function, an error will be generated.

Comment: "The second line of code gets the address of the variable" this is not true.

Comment: Why is it not true?

Comment: Because it declares  a reference parameter - nothing to do with taking the address of anything.

Comment: What is a refrence? It is an address (a pointer). And it is stored on the stack, then used (behind the scenes) to acces the variable. See answer above.

Comment: It's a reference. Another name for an existing object.

Comment: @RobertA., you are going to get some downvotes by mixing a C++ term with implementation. It is true that references are often implemented as pointers (not always, though!) But when you say reference is a pointer, you are making a wrong statement,

Comment: Changed address -> refrence.

Comment: @SergeyA - Can you point me in direction/documentation where/when refrences are not pointers?

Comment: In C++ documentation they are never pointers, they are references. In real life, a non-static reference local to a function body to another variable in the same function will never be a pointer - it will simply not exist after codegen.

Comment: @SergeyA But this question is related to a reference in a function paramater list, which is not the same thing.

Comment: "What is a refrence? It is an address (a pointer)." those were were words.

Answer (score -1):

The `&` specifies that the object is passed by reference (similar to passing by pointer at least on the assembly level). Thus

```
void fval(type x)
{
  // x is a local copy of the data passed by the caller.
  // modifying x has no effect on the data hold by the caller
}
type a;
fval(a);   // a will not be changed

void fref(type &x)
{
  // x is a mere reference to an object
  // changing x affects the data hold by the caller
}
type b;
fref(b);   // b may get changed.
```

Now adding the `const` keyword merely expresses that the function promises not to change the object.

```
void fcval(const type x)
{
  // x is a local copy of the data passed by the caller.
  // modifying x is not allowed
}
type a;
fcval(a);  // a will not be changed

void fcref(const type &x)
{
  // x is a mere reference to an object
  // changing x is not allowed
}
type b;
fcref(b);  // b will not be changed
```

Since a copy may be expensive, it should be avoided if not needed. Therefore, the method of choice for passing a constant object a la `fcref` (except for builtin types when `fval` is fast).

Comment: Often by value in modern C++.

Comment: @SergeyA only if you want to modify or store your local copy.

Comment: Not really. Passing `std::pair<int, int>` by value is usually faster, than by reference.